# c# Substitution Cipher decryption

Tags: c#, encryption, substitution

So I am a teacher and looking to run a little hacking/cryptography club next year.
So I am programming out solutions to a few cryptography methods. I have programmed a randomised substitution cipher but cannot work out the decrypt method with it being random.

I know I need to use letter frequency and pairs of letters of not sure how to program this perfectly.

The sentence I am using is "This is a test of alans cryptography skills"

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the sentence to encrypt");
        string plainText = Console.ReadLine();

        string cipherText = encrypt(plainText.ToUpper());
        Console.WriteLine(cipherText);
        Console.ReadLine();


    }
    public static string encrypt(string phrase)
    {
        List<string> originalLetters = new List<string>();
        //enter the original phrase to the list
        for (int i = 0; i < phrase.Length; i++ )
        {
            originalLetters.Add(phrase[i].ToString());
        }

        //randomise the subsitutions
        //all
        List<string> allLetters = new List<string>{"A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"};

        //shuffled
        List<string> shuffledLetters = new List<string>();
        int times = allLetters.Count;
        Random rng = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < times;i++ )
        {
            int position = rng.Next(0, allLetters.Count);
            shuffledLetters.Add(allLetters[position]);

            Console.Write(allLetters[position] + ", ");
            allLetters.RemoveAt(position);

        }
        Console.WriteLine();
        string cipherText = "";
        //now change letters into shuffled letters
        string SortingLetters = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

        for (int i = 0; i < originalLetters.Count;i++)
        {
            //take the original letter
            //find its position in the sorting letters
            int index = SortingLetters.IndexOf(originalLetters[i]);

            //use position to replace to the new string
            if (index != -1)
            {
                //swap the letter with the index plus the key
                cipherText += shuffledLetters[index];

            }
            else
            {
                cipherText += originalLetters[i];
            }
        }





            //return the encrypted message
            return cipherText;
    }

    public static string decrypt(string phrase)
    {
       //take the encrypted message

        //find most frequent letter as E, focus on single letter words as either I or a



        return "finalAnswer";
    }
}
}
```

I have also included example output. I want to keep this hard for my pupils to crack but just using a set key basically makes it a Caesar cipher which I already have a solution for. I have no problem with the program displaying a range of answers that the user has to find the right one from

Any help is appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Frequency analysis only works if the length of the string is long enough to actually begin displaying the distribution of letters we expect.  At least a few paragraphs I would imagine.

Comment: With a set random key its not a Caesar cipher as there is no fixed shift relationship between the clear text & cypher text.

Comment: Well, see [Letter frequency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_frequency) and then count the characters in the encrypted string (`Dictionary<char, int>` perhaps) and replace according to frequency. But as @LukeJoshuaPark already said, that only works if the `string` is long enough.

Comment: I know it’s not Caesar but the examples of substitution I saw used a set key which was Caesar. Ok so let’s say I put in a paragraph and analyse it. Is there any way to return a variety of answers based upon it? To try and definitely get the correct answer. I have a dictionary of words would it be worth analysing the letter pattern to each word and returning a list of all words that match?

Comment: `shuffledLetters` is needed to decrypt so you could present a variety of candidate alphabets or partial alphabets & have the students iterate over the possible permutations based on the missing characters.

Comment: Yes that’s not a bad idea but would prefer for them to start from nothing and decrypt but that would cut out a lot of possibilities and make it manageable. I will do that as my fall back plan if I cannot get it to work as I will set shuffledLetters to global

Comment: You could just use input text that has a perfect frequency count, i.e make sure there are more E than T than A etc

Comment: I just encrypted most of the wikipedia article [To Kill a Mockingbird](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/To_Kill_a_Mockingbird) and tried a pretty naive implementation of matching the frequency of the encrypted characters to the aforementioned frequency of characters in the english language. -- And out came utter gibberish. The title was guessed as `"OS KHLL N FSCKHRBBHDC"`, so `K` and `L` was guessed correctly, but two different characters were guessed as `C`. So yeah, as @AlexK. said, you'd better look for a very close to perfect input text, or it might turn into a discouraging experience.